# Update by id not does not change a field in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a code in which I am making a new connection using Mongoose and using a schema also. The connection is made properly and I'm also getting the attributes from the collection. After that I want to update in my collection, and that is not working. I have following code

```
console.log("id : "+content._id); 
Alert.findByIdAndUpdate(content._id, {
    $set: {
        status: true
    }
}, function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (error) console.log(error);
    else {
        console.log('Alert updated');
    }
});
```

It shows alert updated but status remains false.

```
result for 1st console is 
id : 55096a5f91169c8e1673af20; 

and 2nd console is
Alert updated
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your schema and the document you're trying to update?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks perfect, the id looks like it's correct and your code don't return any errors, so have you checked your schema to see if it contains the "status" field?

Looks like you can create and edit new documents with a schema that is not equal on both sides, application an data layers.

More info here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1060

Answer (score 0):

Your code also looks right to me, maybe try one of the following?

```
Alert.findOne({_id : content._id}, function(error, alert) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    alert.status = true;
    alert.save();
});
```

Or

```
 Alert.findOneAndUpdate({_id : content._id}, {
        $set: {
            status: true
        }
    }, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else {
            console.log('Alert updated');
        }
    });
```