# Update by id with mongoose doesn't find the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

***Found the problem while writing this.

As it may help others not searching in the right place like me, you will find the answer below.***

I can't seem to make a mongoose [`Model.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) request work, when a [`Model.findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) with the same condition does.

To illustrate, here is my code:
*Schema*:

```
var GeolocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  count: Number
});
```

*An express test route showing the seemingly broken `update` attempt:*

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  var doc = {
    id: '50_633-20_059',
    count: 3,
    density: 1
  };

  var promise = Geoloc.update({
    id: doc.id
  }, {
    $set: {
      density: doc.density
    }
  }).exec();

  promise.then((result, err) => {
    if (err) return next(err, null);
    res.status(201).json(result);
  });
});
```

**Results in:**

```
{
  "ok": 0,
  "n": 0,
  "nModified": 0
}
```

*An express test route showing the working `findOne` call:*

```
router.get('/test2', function(req, res, next) {
  var doc = {
    id: '50_633-20_059',
    count: 3,
    density: 1
  };

  var promise = Geoloc.findOne({
    id: doc.id
  }).exec();

  promise.then((result, err) => {
    if (err) return next(err, null);
    console.log('Update result: ', result);
    res.status(200).json(result);
  });
});
```

**Results in:**

```
{
  "_id": "5885d33239f30034de9a38d0",
  "id": "50_633-20_059",
  "count": 3,
  "__v": 0,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to [this unaccepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391919/3425488) for putting me on the right track.

The culprit was my schema.
Interestingly enough (for a schema-less database), an update operation can't be made on non-existing fields: probably a fail safe to prevent a DB flood from an external source.
*Note that it works as expected via the Mongo CLI.*

Which means that the only necessary change in the code above was the following:

*Schema*:

```
var GeolocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  count: Number,
  density: Number // This is mandatory!
});
```

More infos [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1060).